# how to add a page break in a docx

Tags: python, docx

I would like to add a page break to the pages of my word document so that each statement and its elements are all on the same page.
Here is an example of an unmodified document:
[image: Example 1]

The behavior I would like the code to do would be like this:

[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]

Each question with its respective text and images is on one page

My code that I tried but failed:

```
 def page_break(document):
                page_break_lines = []
                contador = 0

                for pa4 in document.paragraphs:
                    text = pa4.text.strip()
                    if text:
                        if text[0].isdigit() and (text[1] == ')' or text[1] == '.'):
                            contador += 1
                            if contador > 1:
                                pa4.runs[0].add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
                                contador = 0
                            else:
                                contador = 0
                    page_break_lines.append(pa4)

                return page_break_lines
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your code. I hope it will work for you as well.

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_BREAK

def page_break(document):
    page_break_lines = []

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        text = paragraph.text.strip()
        if text:
            if text[0].isdigit() and (text[1] == ')' or text[1] == '.'):
              
                paragraph.runs[0].add_break(WD_BREAK.PAGE)
        page_break_lines.append(paragraph)

    return page_break_lines
```